# Restricting application only to logged users in JSF

Tags: jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces, authentication

In my project to since today I had a login + logout buttons that used JSF Form authentication and simple XHTML j_security_check login page (using primefaces for layout).

```
<form action="j_security_check" method="post">
    <p:panelGrid id="loginContentPanel" columns="2">
        <p:outputLabel for="j_username" value="Login" />
        <p:inputText id="j_username" />
        <p:outputLabel for="j_password" value="Password" />
        <p:password id="j_password"></p:password>
        <f:facet name="footer">
            <div id="loginButtonCenter">
                <h:commandButton id="loginButton"
                    styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only"
                    value="Login" />
            </div>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panelGrid>
</form>
```

Access to page was restricted by following entries in web.xml

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <realm-name>User Auth</realm-name>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.xhtml?s=err</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User Auth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/admin/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

However I'm asked to change login system, so it works in this way:

- Unauthorized user - login page
- Authorized user - portal functionality
- Authorized user with admin role - portal + admin dedicated pages

I modified web.xml to grant access to all roles:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>User Auth</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>*</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

but it still requires me to have at least one role, not being only logged-in. (and I had to change login page to html-only, cause I was getting redirects to jquery style files(?))

I would ask about best approach to do so, but it's best to have closed questions, soooo here is a bunch:

- For now my xhtml files are placed directly in WebContent directory, and in admin directory for admin pages. Should I move rest of the files (except login page) to for example user directory, so I can restrict only area of my project and use PF styles and images on login page?
- I've read about filters, so I could just redirect users that are not logged to login page. Is it secure and cannot be interrupted? Does j_security_check "works" well with filters?
- Is it even possible to restrict application only to logged users using only application web.xml file?

Working on TomEE 1.7.3

Comment: Just add kind of "user" role? The admins obviously have both "user" and "admin" roles. Don't do filters, they are for homegrown security only, not container managed security.

Comment: Well that is what I would do too, but it's now project requirement, that application is available to all users without additional role...

Comment: There can't be users without any role. Just create a new role representing "without role" state.

Comment: Well if you say so, it has to be true! :) Thanks again. I will bug my admin mates then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *but it still requires me to have at least one role, not being only logged-in.*

Just add a role representing an "user without role", e.g. `user`. The admins obviously own both roles.

---

> *(and I had to change login page to html-only, cause I was getting redirects to jquery style files(?))*

The URL pattern of `/*` applies to all requests, including JSF resource requests (CSS/JS/image files from `WAR/resources` and `WAR/WEB-INF/lib/*.jar!/META-INF/resources`). To fix this, just add `/javax.faces.resource/*` URL pattern to the set of publicly allowed resources (i.e. having no auth constraint).

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Allowed resources</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <!-- No Auth Contraint! -->
</security-constraint>
```

See also [PrimeFaces CSS skin not showing in login page, also JavaScript undefined errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13822978/primefaces-css-skin-not-showing-in-login-page-also-javascript-undefined-errors).

---

> *For now my xhtml files are placed directly in WebContent directory, and in admin directory for admin pages. Should I move rest of the files (except login page) to for example user directory, so I can restrict only area of my project and use PF styles and images on login page?*

Not necessary. Just constraint URL pattern `/*` to `user` role and `/admin/*` to `admin` role.

---

> *I've read about filters, so I could just redirect users that are not logged to login page. Is it secure and cannot be interrupted? Does j_security_check "works" well with filters?*

Don't mix them. Filters are for homegrown security only. See also [How to handle authentication/authorization with users in a database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9965708/how-to-handle-authentication-authorization-with-users-in-a-database) Moreover, container managed security runs far before first filter is hit, so you won't have any chance to do something in a filter anyway. See also a.o. [Servlet filter not applying to container managed login page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33252104/servlet-filter-not-applying-to-container-managed-login-page/).